# XCode EXC_BAD_ACCESS by Changing Variable Name

Tags: c, xcode, exc-bad-access

Take this simple program and run it in Xcode:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "inttypes.h"

    struct {
    int32_t nwgts;
;
} clbint_;

#define clbint_1 clbint_

int main()
{
    
    printf("clbint_1.nwgts: %d\n",clbint_1.nwgts);
    clbint_1.nwgts=1; //Crash here
    printf("clbint_1.nwgts: %d\n",clbint_1.nwgts);
    return 0;
}
```

And when you run it you will get a crash on the line indicated that just says `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x10078e18c)`. But if you change `clbint_` to `clbinta_` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "inttypes.h"
struct {
    int32_t nwgts;
;
} clbinta_;

#define clbint_1 clbinta_

int main()
{
    
    printf("clbint_1.nwgts: %d\n",clbint_1.nwgts);
    clbint_1.nwgts=1;
    printf("clbint_1.nwgts: %d\n",clbint_1.nwgts);
    return 0;
}
```

The results print exactly as I expect:

```
clbint_1.nwgts: 0
clbint_1.nwgts: 1
```

I am trying to understand why this is happening, clearly it has something to do with the variable name `clbint_` but why does this behavior occur?

Comment: Now it does. This is a minimal reproducible example. All of the code there is all I have running.

Comment: Works for me.  How are you building?

Comment: It's unlikely to be related to the name of the variable. More likely something messed up with your specific set up. Suggest you do more troubleshooting such as compiling and running directly on the command line, disassembling the binaries to check for differences, running on a different machine, etc.

Comment: @StephenNewell I have it in a .C file that is built with an Xcode project consisting of mostly Swift code and I link it with my bridging header to call the C code from Swift.

Comment: Does the code work as a standalone application, the way you presented it in this question?